# Concatenate a string after variable in PHP

Tags: php

I want to concatenate string after variable in PHP. dot operator is not working.

```
foreach ($get_cont as $line)
{

    #var_dump($line);
    if (strpos($line, "a href"))
    {

        #echo "$line";
        $get_core++;
        if ($get_core == 3)
        {
            #echo $line;
            break 1;
        }
    }
}
#echo $line;
$array = explode(' ', $line);
$core = $array[count($array) - 1];
$core = substr_replace($core, "", -1);

$cmd = "cmd /c curl http://" . $server["server_name"] . ":" . $server["port"] . "/solr" . "/" . $core . "/admin/registry.jsp";
var_dump($cmd);
```

The output should be like:

```
cmd /c curl http://server_name:8080/solr/"value of variable core"/admin/registry.jsp.
```

Please suggest. "." operator is not working.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: Please share `print_r($get_cont)`

Comment: Your syntax is wonky. Check your quotes.

Comment: `$cmd = "cmd /c curl http://" . $server["server_name"] . ":" . $server["port"] . "/solr/" . $core . "/admin/registry.jsp";` that should return correct result

Answer (score 0):

```
$cmd = "cmd /c curl http://" . $server["server_name"] . ":" . $server["port"] . "/solr" . "/" . $core . "/admin/registry.jsp";
```

You've used double quotes for array keys in your variables and to identify your text string. You can see in the syntax highlighting that it is parsing those parts as strings rather than keys as part of your variable/array. You should either use single quotes or use curly braces to declare the variable.

Try

```
$cmd = "cmd /c curl http://{$server['server_name']}:{$server['port']}/solr/{$core}/admin/registry.jsp";
```

OR

```
$cmd = "cmd /c curl http://" . $server['server_name'] . ":" . $server['port']  . "/solr/" . $core . "/admin/registry.jsp";
```

Comment: My syntax was terrible in the second example (missed most of the concatenation). It has been corrected.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` and so fort. Seems OP is confused

Comment: it didn't work. The main problem is that whatever I try to concatenate after "$core", it does not gets added.

Comment: I have shared the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access super global variable `$_SERVER` with `$server`, For this you have to use `$_SERVER`, For accessing server name you should use `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` and for accessing server port you should use `$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]`

**Change this to:**

```
$cmd = "cmd /c curl http://" . $server["server_name"] . ":" . $server["port"] . "/solr" . "/" . $core . "/admin/registry.jsp";
```

**This:**

```
$cmd = "cmd /c curl http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . "/solr/"  . $core . "/admin/registry.jsp";
```

**Try this:**

```
<?php
$get_cont=array("<a href='www.google.com'>");
foreach ($get_cont as $line)
{

    #var_dump($line);
    if (strpos($line, "a href"))
    {

        #echo "$line";
        $get_core++;
        if ($get_core == 3)
        {
            #echo $line;
            break 1;
        }
    }
}
;
$array = explode(' ', $line);

$core = $array[count($array) - 1];
$core = substr_replace($core, "", -1);


echo $cmd = "cmd /c curl http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . "/solr/" . $core . "/admin/registry.jsp";
```

Comment: it didn't work too. Main issue is that whatever I am trying to add after $core, its doesn't gets appended.

Comment: @MukundSharma Can you share `print_r($get_cont);`?

Comment: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] =>
Welcome to Solr!
[14] => Solr [15] => [16] => [17] => Admin cpat [18] => 
[19] => [20] => Admin infra [21] => 
[22] => [23] => Admin infra_temp [24] => 
[25] => [26] => Admin know_autosuggest [27] => 
[28] => [29] => Admin wordviz [30] => 
[31] => [32] => Admin ps_sln_web [33] => 
[34] => [35] => Admin ps_sln_web_temp [36] => 
[37] => [38] => Admin knuggets_tags_autosuggest [39] => 
[40] => [41] => Admin knuggets_tags_autosuggest_temp [42] =>

Comment: @MukundSharma can you please share this result in your post?

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me. I handled the values as string instead of storing it in array:

```
                        #echo $line;
                        $core="";
                        $core_temp="";
                        $core_temp=strip_tags($line);
                        $core=substr($core_temp, strpos($core_temp, " ") + 1);

                        #$array=explode(' ', $line);
                        #$core = $array[count($array)-1];
                        #$core=substr_replace($core, "", -1);
                        #var_dump($core);
                        #echo "$core";
```